# Function does not exit after foreach loop and realod function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, curl, php-curl

I have a function in php that this function connect to multiple API and get data from this multiple API and insert into database. but when function get data from last API , function does not exit. function reload and get data from  multiple API again. why function reloaded ?

**note : this function worked in localhost without problem but in dedicated server function reloaded**

```
function sepehr_get_flight(){

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `status` = ?', array(1));

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $domain){

        $url = $domain['url'];

        $data = array(
            "UserName"=> "",
            "Password"=> "",
        );

        $content = json_encode($data);

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($curl);

        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($curl);

        $info = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);

        $count = count($info['Priced']);

        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
           if(!empty($info)){

               // insert data to database

           }
        }

    }

    echo 'Success';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Try to add log for each for loop execution. It will helps to understand the execution.

Comment: Show full code. There is no refresh or redirect code and php doesn't just do what it feels like. Are you using Js to call the function?

Comment: I do not use Js to call the function